# How to Authenticate with API Key - Django Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm making an internal API with TastyPie. I have

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.authentication import ApiKeyAuthentication
from myapp.movie.models import Movie


class MovieResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Movie.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'movie'
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
```

With Auth rules disabled, my API works great. With it on, I get a 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) response.

URL is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movie/?format=json
```

thank you

UPDATE: I've same problem. [Django Tastypie: How to Authenticate with API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814128/django-tastypie-how-to-authenticate-with-api-key)

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually provide the API Key with your request.

You mentioned the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movie/?format=json
```

but since you didn't say otherwise I assume it's GET and therefore it should include the api key, for example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movie/?format=json&api_key=123456789adfljafal
```

If this doesn't help, please provide more information.