# appending multiple querystring variables with curl

Tags: django, curl, tastypie

I keep getting a 401 response when I try to use authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication() in my ModelResource.
I looked at [Django Tastypie: How to Authenticate with API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814128/django-tastypie-how-to-authenticate-with-api-key) and he uses the get parameters to solve his issue. If I try use get parameters it picks up username but not api_key!

**This works in browser**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/spot/8/?username=darren&api_key=xxxxx
```

**Sending via curl in terminal doesn't pickup api_key parameter**

```
curl --dump-header - http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/spot/8/?username=darren&api_key=xxxxx
```

Why when using curl and appending 2 querystring parameters like `?username=darren&api_key=xxxxx` does it only pickup the first one. Is this not the correct way?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Typing `&` in the command line means run the preceding command in the background (thanks @Maccesch), because of this anything after the `&` is being treated as a new command.

Try wrapping the url in quotes.

`curl --dump-header - "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/spot/8/?username=darren&api_key=xxxxx"`

Comment: You are right, `&` means to run the preceeding command in the background. The string afterwards is considered a new command.

Comment: @Maccesch, cheers, I had a feeling it was that from when I was running a Apache Solr instance on my local VM.

Comment: Depending on OS and curl build, it might be single or double-quotes, too.  (Had to use singles to get ODATA ?$top=1 to work on OSX.)