# spring data rest + custom method: Paging, sorting doesnt work

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

so my interface:

```
public interface SubmissionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Submission, Long> {
//all by approval phase
@RestResource(path="byApprovalPhase")
List<Submission> findByApprovalPhase(@Param("approvalPhase") ApprovalPhase approvalPhase);
//paging + sorting
@RestResource(path="byApprovalPhasePaging")
Page<Submission> findByApprovalPhase(@Param("approvalPhase") ApprovalPhase approvalPhase, Pageable pageable);
//all with sorting
@RestResource(path="byApprovalPhaseSorting")
List<Submission> findByApprovalPhase(@Param("approvalPhase") ApprovalPhase approvalPhase, Sort pageable);
}
```

so I get those methods in json/hal `curl -v http://localhost:8080/submissions/search`

```
....
"_links" : {
"findByApprovalPhase" : [ {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/submissions/search/byApprovalPhase{?approvalPhase}",
  "templated" : true
}, {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/submissions/search/byApprovalPhasePaging{?approvalPhase,page,size,sort}",
  "templated" : true
}, {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/submissions/search/byApprovalPhaseSorting{?approvalPhase}",
  "templated" : true
} ]
}
...
```

but `curl -v http://localhost:8080/submissions/search/byApprovalPhasePaging?approvalPhase=PENDING&page=1&size=5`

returns default 20 rows. Same thing with sorting - it doesnt work ( no error, just sorting has no effect). Dont know what is missed here.

//edit:

similar thing for localhost:8080/submissions - there are 14 rows total, by default it shows 20. 
`curl -v http://localhost:8080/submissions?size=1`returns 1st one, but `curl -v http://localhost:8080/submissions?page=1&size=1` returns only _links to prev, next.

My repository extends PagingAndSortingRepository..

Comment: Spring pagination starts with 0. So try with page=0 for first page.Also what version of SDR are you using?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/submissions?page=0&size=1 ignores size parameter - returns all 20 ( well - 14 in  this case because thats all I got ). Same with my custom method on http://localhost:8080/submissions/search/byApprovalPhasePaging?approvalPhase=PENDING&page=0&size=1.  Its SDR 2.1.4.

Comment: SDR 2.1.4 works perfectly for me with page=0&size=1. Check again

Answer (score 1):

Silly thing.. We had to use "" around url when testing using curl.. otherwise it treat everything after & as other parameter.. more details here [appending multiple querystring variables with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978474/appending-multiple-querystring-variables-with-curl)