# TastyPie and Django authorization with ApiKeyAuthentication

Tags: django, tastypie

I've been struggling with this for a bit, pouring over a bunch of other SO answers but can't seem to figure out how to authenticate a user to my Django site using the ApiKeyAuthentication.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814128/django-tastypie-how-to-authenticate-with-api-key) the accepted answer states "Add the username and api_key parameters to your GET variables". My question is, how do I know what the api key is, if TastyPie is generating the key for me? If I wanted to create my *own* key, where would I put that key?

Here's my api.py:

```
class SystemResource(ModelResource):
  user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

  class Meta:
    querySet = System.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'system'
    authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
```

When I call the URL: `http://192.168.1.130:8080/systems/api/v1/user/?username=garfonzo&api_key=123456789` it fails, kicking me to my login page. Of course, the `123456789` is quite made up, I have not listed that key anywhere so in some ways it's obvious this is failing).

In the docs, it discusses [either](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#apikeyauthentication) creating an Authorization header, or supplying the username/api_ky in the request. But again, if I'm supplying the api_key in the request, how do I know what *that* key should be? Where is it defined on the server?

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create an API Key for your Tastypie you should go to the Admin site, and in the TastyPie app, add a new API Key. Choose the user, leave the key blank, and it will autogenerate one for you ;)

Comment: Ah, nice that's where I create the api_key. So next question, if I have a middleware that kicks you to the login page if you haven't logged in, can TastyPie deal with? Somehow tell Django that this user can access the data. Isn't that the point of `ApiKeyAuthentication`?

Comment: Well that's a totally different question. You should open another question, and I will try to answer there. This way people will be able to find both questions without looking in the comments on a totally unrelated one ;) And also, if this answer helped, please mark it as accepted! Cheers

Comment: Thanks, your solution did help. I've opened another post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573037/django-tastypie-authentication-and-custom-middleware-headache